# Finding $y=\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5 + \ldots}}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

I can't find the answer to this problem

> Find $y$ when
>
> $y=\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5 + \ldots}}}}$

Any help is appreciated. Thank You

Comment: You mean $y=\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\dots }}}$?  If so, then Hint:  Square the equation to get a quadratic expression in $y$.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean yes thank you

Comment: Sorry for that I didn't see that answer before I apologize for my mistake

Comment: *IF* the number exists then $y = \sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5+...}}$ Then $y^2 = 5 + \sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5+...}} $ then $y^2 = 5 + y$ so $y^2 - y - 5 = 0$.  Use the quadraditic equation  However, I'd be remiss if I didn't warn that just because one can write an expression doesn't mean it has a value.  (Ex: x = 1+ 2 + 4 + 8 +... doesn't have an answer.)

Comment: @RayyanMerchant No problem! The keyword was "nested radicals", and it takes practice to search the site; thanks for being a good sport :)

Comment: @fleablood Just to be goofy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF